# How to Use ECMA CSOM to Set a Field of Type SPFieldUserValue

Tags: javascript, client-object-model, user

I have a JavaScript array containing the string representation of some usernames (domain\username format).

Using the JavaScript CSOM, what is the best way to create a new item and add those usernames to that new item's multiple value user field?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

According to [How to set people and group column programmatically using Client Object Model](http://passionatetechie.blogspot.dk/2012/01/how-to-set-people-and-group-column.html) this is how you set single user fields:

```
 SP.User _newUser = _ctx.Web.EnsureUser("domain\\username");
 _ctx.Load(_newUser);
 _ctx.ExecuteQuery();

 SP.FieldUserValue _userValue = new SP.FieldUserValue();
 _userValue.LookupId = _newUser.Id;
 _listItem["userfield"] = _userValue;
 _listItem.Update();
 _ctx.ExecuteQuery();
```

According to [Add multiple people using Javascript Client Object Model](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-IE/sharepoint2010programming/thread/2c113538-cbbf-4337-8cf5-9c406f9012cb) the following should work for Multi user fields:

```
var users = new Array();
users.push(SP.FieldUserValue.fromUser("testAias1"));
users.push(SP.FieldUserValue.fromUser("testAias2"));

item.set_item(columnName, users);
item.update();
```

Comment: Isn't that managed Client Object Model? My question is regarding JavaScript. Also, what I am really having an issue with is that this must be **multiple** users.

Comment: This is JavaScript CSOM you can see that from all the `SP.` which isn't used in managed CSOM. I've added some multi user code. You may have to mix the two samples.

Comment: Thanks, top one is managed client object model, though.

Comment: Per, thanks for being such an awesome contributor to this community. Any way I can show my gratitude for all times you've answered my questions?

Comment: Yes you're right the first example is managed sorry.

Comment: Regarding showing gratitude. You just did. Appart from that I prefer you to "pay it forward". And if we meet at a Conference you can buy me a Coke Zero.

Comment: I have same problem, using javascript and array, but it works only when the array contains one item. when the array contains more than one item it generates error.

Comment: I have same problem, using javascript and array, but it works only when the array contains one item. when the array contains more than one item it generates error. I am using a client side people picker when people picker contains more than one item it fails. is there another solution for that?

Answer (score 3):

The Multiple User field is internally just a LookUp Field. The following code should work:

```
var users = new Array();

users.push(SP.FieldUserValue.fromUser("userName1"));
users.push(SP.FieldUserValue.fromUser("userName2"));

item.set_item(fieldName, users);
item.update();
```

Instead of `SP.FieldUserValue.fromUser("userName1")` you can use your existing `SP.FieldUserValue` object. Also make sure that the column is set to accept multiple users as input. You can set this in the column settings.

Comment: Thank you both! I knew it had to be easier than I was making it out to be.

Answer (score 1):

The above solution didn't work for me. It is described here: [Add multiple people using Javascript Client Object Model to a Field of Type SPFieldUserValue](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/55399/add-multiple-people-using-javascript-client-object-model-to-a-field-of-type-spfi/57257#57257)

This is what worked for me:

```
var users = User1_ID + ';#' + User1_Name + ';#' + User2_ID + ';#' + User2_Name;

listItem.set_item(fieldName, users); listItem.update();
```