# Is Multiple Lookup API's supported JavaScript

Tags: lookup-column

Is Multiple Lookup API's supported JavaScript language?

I need to create a new column, retrieve data from multi-lookup using JavaScript API's
not sure if it's supported.

Answer (score 1):

As I know it is supported, [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/47872/how-to-use-ecma-csom-to-set-a-field-of-type-spfielduservalue/47884#47884) is an example how to use multi-user values for SPFieldUser. SPFieldUser is a field that is works similar as lookup.

The simple search give me this [link](http://ozkary.blogspot.com/2012/06/set-sharepoint-multi-value-field-with.html).