# Add multiple people using Javascript Client Object Model to a Field of Type SPFieldUserValue

Tags: javascript, client-object-model, user

I want to update a UserField client side.
I found the following code at this topic [How to Use ECMA CSOM to Set a Field of Type SPFieldUserValue](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/47872/how-to-use-ecma-csom-to-set-a-field-of-type-spfielduservalue)

Tried the following code:

```
var users = new Array();

users.push(SP.FieldUserValue.fromUser("testAias1"));
users.push(SP.FieldUserValue.fromUser("testAias2"));

item.set_item(columnName, users);

item.update();
```

I'm getting the following error:

> "Invalid look-up value. A look-up field contains invalid data. Please
>   check the value and try again."

It's not working if I want to add an array of users to a field. It only works for one user ex:

```
item.set_item(columnName, SP.FieldUserValue.fromUser("testAias1"));
```

Any ideas why?

Answer (score 4):

Ok, so I finally figured it out.
This is what worked for me:

```
var users = User1_ID + ';#' + User1_Name + ';#' + User2_ID + ';#' + User2_Name;
listItem.set_item(fieldName, users);
listItem.update();
```

Comment: Hi,
I have used client side people picker, and I have same problem as you have, how do I get User_id and User_name from a people picker Entity? thank you for your help.

Answer (score -1):

Building on the answer from i_borgos this also works without the Display Name if that is unavailable.

```
var users = User1_ID + ';#;#' + User2_ID;
listItem.set_item(fieldName, users);
listItem.update();
```

Answer (score -5):

get all fields and just split with the help of JQuery