# Fill SharePoint list element field (people picker) with JavaScript

Tags: list, javascript, error, jsom, people-picker

I want to add a list element via JavaScript which works (almost).

After the help from a user here I got this

```
function fillStandard() {
    console.log("Standard");
    var posInvest =  "Invest"; 
    var posRecipient = accResponsible;
    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Position');
    var item = new SP.ListItemCreationInformation();

    var oListItem = oList.addItem(item);
    oListItem.set_item('PosType', posInvest);
    oListItem.set_item('Recipient', posRecipient);

    oListItem.update();
    clientContext.load(oListItem);
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));
}

function onQuerySucceeded(sender, args) {
    console.log("successfully executed");
}

function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
    console.log("failed");
    alert('request failed ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}
```

If I outcomment `oListItem.set_item('Recipient', posRecipient);` it works.

The problem is that I have defined `accResponsible` as

```
var accResponsible = "[{\"email\":\"john.doe@blabla.net\",\"id\":\"i:0#.w|opmain\\\\eojdoe\",\"label\":\"John, Doe\",\"title\":\"\",\"type\":\"User\",\"value\":\"i:0#.w|opmain\\\\eojdoe\"}]";
```

which gives an error (invalid data has been used to update the field)

The field should normally get the value of a user (peoplePicker), for example something like this

```
posRecipient = NWF$("#" +varManager1).val(accResponsible);
```

But when I do that, the field remains blank. 
Does someone know how to solve this?

[image: recipient]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the value you have in this variable `accResponsible`. User field in SharePoint list cannot be update using a var value, we need a `SP.FieldUserValue` to put it into the list.

I find answer here using the person name instead the id is more easy than find user id if you don't have it.

[How to set any SP.Field Value with JSOM (Javascript) in Sharepoint 2013](https://gist.github.com/rheid/18635032d8371c7825b3320eae57071f).

```
// Single Person  
var singleUser = SP.FieldUserValue.fromUser('Peter Dotsenko');  
oListItem.set_item('PetkaPersonSingle', singleUser);  

//Multi Person  
var petkaUserMultiArray = new Array("peterd@domain.com","Peter Dotsenko","domain\\peterd");  
var lookups = [];  
for (var ii in petkaUserMultiArray) {  
   var lookupValue = SP.FieldUserValue.fromUser(petkaUserMultiArray[ii]);  
   lookups.push(lookupValue);  
}  
oListItem.set_item('PetkaPersonMulti', lookups);
```

For more information, refer the below links:

1. [The proper way to write a SharePoint User to a User Field in a SharePoint list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24271440/the-proper-way-to-write-a-sharepoint-user-to-a-user-field-in-a-sharepoint-list)
   .
2. [Add multiple people using Javascript Client Object Model to a Field of Type SPFieldUserValue](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/55399/add-multiple-people-using-javascript-client-object-model-to-a-field-of-type-spfi).

Comment: I love you man. Thanks a lot bhai!!