# User or group column is populated with incorrect values when adding data from CSOM

Tags: client-object-model

I am working on a console application that updates list items using managed CSOM. I have a user or group column in this list that can contain multiple values. Now, I am using below code to update the value of this column:

```
// Get the user  
User newUser = web.EnsureUser("LoginName");  
context.Load(newUser);  
context.ExecuteQuery();  
FieldUserValue userValue = new FieldUserValue();  
userValue.LookupId = newUser.Id;

// Update the list item  
listItem["User"] = userValue;
```

The issue is if I assign the value of user1 to this column, the value that I see after the column is updated is another user; like user2. I don't know why it is populating this code with some other user?

Any idea on this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You should call `Update()` and `ExecuceQuery()` at the end of the code as shown [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/47872/how-to-use-ecma-csom-to-set-a-field-of-type-spfielduservalue):

```
 Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.User _newUser = _ctx.Web.EnsureUser("domain\\username");
 _ctx.Load(_newUser);
 _ctx.ExecuteQuery();

 Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.FieldUserValue _userValue = new Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.FieldUserValue();
 _userValue.LookupId = _newUser.Id;
 _listItem["userfield"] = userValue;
 _listItem.Update();
 _ctx.ExecuteQuery();
```

I suggest you to use [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) to see the network traffic between client and server.

Comment: Yes, I am doing it. Forgot to add that part in the question. I am updating the list item and then firing ExecuteQuery as well.